# UITableView cell allocate mark when checked...it would checked automatically when scrolling tblview

Tags: ios, tableview, uitableview

When i select index 0 or 1 or any else that same time it also selected index according to above index
i need solution
there are many rows and when i select cell 1 same time another cell selected automatically..

Comment: I think your question is not clear. Please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath * checkedIndexPath;
```

in ViewDidLoad

```
    self.checkedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];//Default 1st row will be checkMarked

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kSimpleCell];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kSimpleCell]autorelease];
    }
    if (self.checkedIndexPath== indexPath)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *currentcell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.checkedIndexPath];
    currentcell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;
    UITableViewCell *currentcell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.checkedIndexPath];
    currentcell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Comment: let me know the result

Comment: its done...thank you very much to help me out from this problem.. :)

Comment: Some optimisation is possible.if u want i ll do that